# Recurrent Mixture Density Networks for Tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow

Is there an implementation of Schuster's [Recurrent Mixture Density Networks](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/amos/pmrg/schuster.pdf) for Tensorflow yet?  They were used by Alex Graves to great effect in his "[Generating Sequences With Recurrent Neural Networks](http://arxiv.org/abs/1308.0850)" paper and [handwriting generation demo](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~graves/handwriting.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I looks like someone [made a version of the handwriting generation code in Tensorflow](http://blog.otoro.net/2015/12/12/handwriting-generation-demo-in-tensorflow/).  It includes [code](https://github.com/hardmaru/write-rnn-tensorflow) for a 2D Recurrent Mixture Density Network.

Comment: Has anybody seen a version of this that works in current Tensorflow (1.1) and perhaps uses the built in mixture model? It would be great to use such networks without quite as much custom code for sampling from the network etc.

Answer (score 1):

Not yet, but good point. Recurrent neural nets are in TensorFlow, if you combine those with a loss that maximizes likelihood of a Gaussian distribution then you can set this up. We haven't tried this yet but theoretically it should be possible with what is there now -- however, it may be possible to simplify it by having a special loss for this case (which we currently don't have).

Comment: See my new answer; it looks like someone already implemented it!